# Textfield in the keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-softkeyboard

How do you make a keyboard have a textfield inside like the messages app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

never tried but you can try this -

You can programmatically

1. set a tool bar.
2. set a textfield.
3. set the  tool bar as the inputAccessoryView of the textfield.
4. make the textfield the first responder.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're trying to do with it. You could simply create a view that looks like the keyboard section and show it right above the keyboard. If you're trying to actually send SMSs/emails, look up the MessageUI documentation.

Comment: I realised that later that the MessageUI is meant for actually sending SMS and mails.
What I wanted was to have a keyboard similar to the ones in apps like Meebo, Messages, IM apps, thats it no sending actual messages

Comment: Which is why I mentioned floating a UIView on top of your views that appears right above the keyboard. It doesn't have to be part of the keyboard. You could also message one of those apps devs - us devs have to work together, one of them might share their secret.